# Why the MySQL statement I wrote does not match the index

Tags: mysql

This table is about another 700,000 pieces of data, and I've built four indexes for this table

```
illegal_type    illegal_type    NORMAL
illegal_time    illegal_time, audit_status, uploading_status    NORMAL
device_id       device_id   NORMAL

EXPLAIN SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() over ( ORDER BY alarm_sum DESC ) ranking,
i.device_name deviceName,
i.device_id deviceId,
alarm_sum illegalCount FROM
(
SELECT
    any_value ( device_name ) device_name,
    device_id device_id,
    COUNT( 1 ) alarm_sum 
FROM
    illegal_record 
WHERE
    illegal_time >= 1627747200000 
    AND illegal_time <= 1630771199000 
    AND audit_status = 1 
GROUP BY
    device_id 
) i 
LIMIT 10 

1   PRIMARY <derived2>      ALL                 69527   100.00  Using filesort
2   DERIVED illegal_record      index   (possible_key)device_id,illegal_time    (key)device_id  98      747135  9.31    Using where
```

```html
CREATE TABLE `illegal_record` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL COMMENT 'id',
  `illegal_time` bigint NOT NULL COMMENT 'Illegal time',
  `device_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'device id ',
  `device_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'device name',
  `audit_status` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'audit status',
  `audit_time` bigint DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp',
  `audit_user_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'audit user id ',
  `audit_user_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'auditor',
  `uploading_status` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `uploading_time` bigint DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `illegal_type` (`illegal_type`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `device_id` (`device_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `illegal_time` (`illegal_time`,`audit_status`,`uploading_status`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `audit_time` (`audit_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Illegal_time is the timestamp, I hope to hit the illegal_time composite index, but remove the device_id index to scan all.
Why can't hit it?Is a full table scan faster than an index scan?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Uploading the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE illegal_record;` [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69053416/edit) could help.

Comment: "ndexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables where report queries process most or all of the rows. When a query needs to access most of the rows, reading sequentially is faster than working through an index. Sequential reads minimize disk seeks, even if not all the rows are needed for the query." (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: Because you only do a `LIMIT 10`, and no `ORDER BY`, it will become unclear which 10 records will be selected...

Comment: @FaNo_FN I'm not allowed to place pictures，Device_ID is a common index illegal_time 
contains [`illegal_time`, `audit_status`] ，But the above SQL statement  just use device_id

Comment: @demoTestABC: You are allowed to upload images, but they should add info to your question. The current 2 pictures only contain some TEXT, which should have been posted as TEXT, and not as a picture.   The output form a `CREATE TABLE ....` also only contains text, and not a picture.

Comment: @Luuk The question is updated

Comment: Is the `illegal_time` column suppose to store time in `unixtime` format?

Answer (score 1):

Your `where` clause is:

```
WHERE illegal_time >= 1627747200000 AND
      illegal_time <= 1630771199000 AND
      audit_status = 1
```

The optimal index for this would be `(audit_status, illegal_time)`. The equality predicates should be in the index first.  You should also include `device_id` and `device_name` so the index covers the subquery.